# erro ao tentar gerar apk android

Tags: android, apk

Estou tentando gerar apk , mais está dando erro , não to entendendo

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key from keystore
```

Evente log

```
19:33:33 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 3 min 21 sec
19:33:44 Generate signed APK: Errors while building apk, see messages tool window for 
list of errors.
```

Comment: Você chegou a criar a *keystore*? Pelo erro parece que não foi encontrado o *alias* para a chave. Você chegou a ir em Build > Generate Signed APK?

Comment: sim , pode ser que eu estou criando a keystore errado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Failed to read key from key*store*

São várias as possibilidades para este erro surgir. Veja as possíveis abaixo:

- Ao inserir a senha no *menu* para gerar o **APK**, você pode ter errado a senha.
- Antes de poder gerar um **APK**, você obrigatoriamente precisa criar um arquivo `nome.jks` e salvar em uma pasta qualquer. Se caso, este arquivo não existir, esse erro será mostrado.

Outra forma de saber o que está acontecendo, é usando a linha de comando abaixo no *Gradle Command Line*:

`gradle signingReport` - *Windows*